# In Docker Swarm mode, is there a way to restart a Docker service, just before it reaches a specific threshold of cpu or memory?

Tags: docker, containers, devops, docker-swarm

The story goes like this!

1. I have used `Docker Swarm mode` as an orchestration tool!
2. I have deployed my `live_ofbiz` service in swarm mode!
3. Service `live_ofbiz` contains bloated containers, with an image of size 1.25 GB.
4. There is some way or the other, where the container is leaking memory.
5. I have limited the memory usage of the service to 6GB.
   (`docker stats`)[image: docker stats]
6. With about 150 daily users on the application, the container is **bound to die after 10-12 days**, leaving a downtime of 2 minutes, **when the memory limit capacity of 6GB** is reached!

---

So my question is, is there any way through which I can set a threshold limit of 6GB, and in the meantime, a new container can launch itself and replace the `live_ofbiz`'s running container (just like `docker service update --image ofbiz:$SAME_OLD_IMAGE_VERSION live_ofbiz`, but in an automated fashion)?

> A possible solution can be adding a corn job to identify the memory
> limit reached, and hence triggering the update command via shell! But
> I would refrain from using a corn job due to some restrictions!

I'd like to know if Docker Swarm mode / Services configuration provides such a solution by default or not!

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Tricky one. `--limit-memory` is literally how docker swarm supports terminating - and restarting leaking tasks. However, there is no "start-first" option for restart policy, only for `--update-order`. So unless `--update-order=start-first` magically applies here, it seems that you need more than 1 replica if you want continuity over the OOM / restart.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Yes! That's the only conclusion I could get to! I am now running two replicas!

Comment: Just feel lucky you arn't running a Java VM. The Java Docker image sets the JVMs max memory to be the containers --limit-memory meaning that Java will fail memory allocations before exceeding Dockers memory allocation. A leaking app goes into a failing state (all allocations fail) but docker doesn't OOM kill it.

Comment: As matter of fact, I am running a JVM! :)
Making the orchestration fault tolerant is the only solution, it seems. I did use multiple scales to fix this issue for now! It shows the limitation of the Docker Swarm. I could not implement Auto Scale yet. I am running a project to transition the orchestration to Kubernetes via AWS EKS

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, unless you have your own API/CRON/... system/application which would be monitoring and then doing the actions needed Docker Swarm does not have a way to do so. You can probably use more than one replica of the "troublesome" service and then whenever the swarm decides to .. kill the "bad" one at least one is still running so you would minimize downtime to almost 0 or 0.